# How to call correctly this function in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code:

```
function changeEventStatusClass(object){
    if ($(object).hasClass("fa-circle")) {
        $(object).removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-circle-o");
        //alert("adevarat");
    } else {
        $(object).removeClass("fa-circle-o").addClass("fa-circle");
    }
}

function changeEventStatus(eventId, status) {
    console.log(eventId, status);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            eventId: eventId,
            status: status,
        },
        url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/ajaxupdateappointmentstatus'; ?>",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                console.log(eventId);
                changeEventStatusClass(eventId); //here is problem
            }
        }
    });
}

$(".crad").on('click', function(){
    var eventId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var completed = ($( this ).hasClass("fa-circle-o")) ? true : false;
    console.log(completed);
    if (completed) {
        changeEventStatus(eventId, 7);
    } else {
        changeEventStatus(eventId, 0);
    }
})
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" data-id="241"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" data-id="242"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" data-id="243"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" data-id="244"></i>
```

I have a problem when I try to call the function `changeEventStatusClass` because it is not a parameter ID (it's a `data-id`);

How to order correctly to make this function? Currently the site is changing class to all buttons and I just want the current one

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should just pass the jq object or DOM node reference to function, not a selector string. e.g `changeEventStatus(this,7);`. Or you could bind the relevant context: `changeEventStatus.call(this, 7);` whith `function changeEventStatus(status) {...}` and as ajax option: `context: this,`  Then just use `$(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), Additionally you can also use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove classes.

```
function changeEventStatusClass(object){
    $("[data-id='"+object+"']").toggleClass("fa-circle-o fa-circle");
}
```

However better approach would be to pass the object like

```
function changeEventStatusClass(element){
    element.toggleClass("fa-circle fa-circle-o");
}

function changeEventStatus(element, status) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            eventId: element.attr('data-id'),
            status: status,
        },
        url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/ajaxupdateappointmentstatus'; ?>",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                console.log(eventId);
                changeEventStatusClass(element); //here is problem
            }
        }
    });
}

$(".crad").on('click', function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var eventId = element.attr('data-id');
    var completed = element.hasClass("fa-circle-o");
    if (completed) {
        changeEventStatus(element, 7);
    } else {
        changeEventStatus(element, 0);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to select the element whose `data-id` attribute value is passed by doing

```
object = $( "[data-id='" + object + "']" ); //this line is added
```

change this method as

```
function changeEventStatusClass(object) {
    object = $("[data-id='" + object + "']"); //this line is added
    if ($(object).hasClass("fa-circle")) {
        $(object).removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-circle-o");
        //alert("adevarat");
    } else {
        $(object).removeClass("fa-circle-o").addClass("fa-circle");
    }
}
```